# Enalble Writable FTP or Samba on a ZTE Router(Shipped as Airtel Nokia Router)

Tags: ftp, router, nokia

I have enabled ftp as well as Samba service for the usb device connected to my router. However, both are readonly.

I see that tplink routers can be configured to use ftp in writeable mode as well - https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1158/

Can same be done in the ZTE modems using some advanced page?

[image]

Comment: If you check all the options in router and can't find such you can't do it.